# Handling File Uploads from Mobile Application to a Rails End Point using Shrine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, file-upload, amazon-s3, shrine

So I have a Rails Application which uses Shrine as its File Uploader. The same app has a mobile client which can click and send pictures. Currently, the mobile is clicking pictures and sending them to AWS S3 and then returning the S3 URL back to Rails to associate with the object. At this point, once Shrine received this S3 URL I save it to `object.upload_remote_url`. Following which Shrine again uploads it to S3 thus making 2 requests to S3 for every image that comes via the JSON API.

1. What I would like to know is, what is the best practise to handle file uploads from Mobile to Web Server to S3? What are the best techniques developers use?
2. How to send files from mobile as JSON. I know images can be converted to Base64 String and then sent but what other options are available?
3. Shrine Gem with S3 plugin has a copy option, which correct me if I am wrong, checkes for the image in the source bucket and copies it over to the destination bucket.
   http://shrinerb.com/rdoc/classes/Shrine/Storage/S3.html#class-Shrine::Storage::S3-label-Upload+options

Below is my Shrine Configs

```
require "shrine/storage/s3"

s3_options = {
  access_key_id:     Rails.application.secrets.aws_access_key_id,
  secret_access_key: Rails.application.secrets.aws_secret_access_key,
  region:            Rails.application.secrets.aws_region,
  bucket:            Rails.application.secrets.aws_bucket,
}

copy_from = {
    copy_source: "#{Rails.application.secrets.aws_bucket}/mobile"
}

Shrine.storages = {
  cache: Shrine::Storage::S3.new(prefix: "cache", upload_options: {acl: "public-read"}, **copy_from, **s3_options),
  store: Shrine::Storage::S3.new(prefix: "store", upload_options: {acl: "public-read"}, **copy_from, **s3_options)
}

Shrine.plugin :activerecord
Shrine.plugin :direct_upload
Shrine.plugin :restore_cached_data
Shrine.plugin :upload_options
```

I am trying to work with option #3 but I'm stuck trying to getting it to work. Can anyone help me understand it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As far as I know, the best practices for uploads from Mobile to Web Server are exactly the same as from Browser to Web Server. I always advocate uploading directly to an external service (S3), and then sending just the identifier to the Web Server (rather than uploading the file directly to the Web Server).
2. The standard way of sending files is either via a `multipart/form-data` encoded request, or via a Data URI (where the file content can optionally be base64-encoded). Using the data URI is especially common when you're doing client-side image processing, because most libraries return a Data URI as the result.
3. Sending the S3 URL to the `remote_url` attribute is definitely not optimal, because then Shrine will download the file from S3 and re-upload it to the temporary storage. Shrine works in a way that it first uploads the file to temporary storage, and then after validations pass the file is moved to permanent storage.

   The idea of "direct uploads" in Shrine is that the *client* is the one that uploads the file to temporary storage (in this case S3), and sends it to the server as an "already uploaded file"; then Shrine only needs to move it to permanent storage (which can be moved to a background job).

   The format in which client needs to send the S3 identifier is the following:

   ```
   {
     "storage": "cache",
     "id": "<object-key>",
     "metadata": {...}
   }
   ```

   - `storage` - the identifier of the temporary storage registered in `Shrine.storages` (typically "cache")
   - `id` – the key of the S3 object, minus the `:prefix` option if it's set when initializing Shrine::Storage::S3
   - `metadata` – any metadata that the client extracted and wants to send

Comment: Firstly, thanks mate for the info! So if I understood this correctly (the last part).. All I gotta do is upload to S3 cache folder from client side and in response, the key that I get is to be set as id along with other data as mentioned above in JSON? Also your answer is perfectly acceptable and I wish I could upvote it if not for the low points I have?

Comment: Okay I got this to work! @janko-m Shrine is the coolest file uploader gem. Thanks!